# Is 播主 actually a word?

Tags: usage, word

I'm getting into making YouTube videos, and sometimes I find it hard to express the concept of a "YouTuber".  I've been calling myself a 播主, but it's not in the CC-CEDICT, and maybe I should be saying 主播:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%BB%E6%92%AD): 主播 (zhǔ​bō​) (news) anchor / (program) host / (Internet) streamer

A few days ago, I was chatting with someone in Beijing after making a video, and he used 播主, which really makes me think it's a real word.  But he was like 15 or something, and maybe he was just copying me.

**Question**: Is 播主 actually a word?

It makes logical sense to me: I am the 播主 = 播放主人.

Answer (score 5):

播主 is not yet a Mandarin word as recognized by linguistic authorities of Chinese, a language severely liable to governmental language planning. It has not been included in any published dictionary in the mainland. It is rather young a word that has just come around (in mainland) since Douyin/TikTok, Kuaishou (and other minor streaming/short video platforms) took the country by storm in Cyberspace, so it is significantly less seen compared to 主播.

You will be, however, readily understood if you go on to use it in ways like the one in your description as it does invite swift comprehension. I am also confident that it is going quickly to make its way into mainstream usage; actually it is doing this now, see [1](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1721716651724852371), [2](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1661305411548717699).

P.S. Not that I'm sure about this, but since 直播主 is the predominant way for saying it (besides 實況主) in Taiwan, using 播主 may, if slightly, suggest a Taiwanese flavor in your speech, or unfamiliarity with Mandarin.

Answer (score 2):

播主 is actually a word.

In this Taiwanese article, you could find 直播主.

https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/147644/1/13597.pdf

Answer (score 2):

主播 usually refers people who do live streaming (直播).

You are a YouTuber but you record and clip and upload. This kind of content creators are usually referred to as "up 主" on Bilibili, one of the popular online video platforms like YouTube in China.

That is right, it is not a Chinese word, but it is oral. To be formal, then it could be 内容创作者 (content creator), 视频博主 (vlogger).

---

PS: Though I never actually noticed anybody using 播主, I do understand what that could be, so probably no big deal. Some people might think it is 博主 mispronounced though. After all 视频博主 is a kind of 博主.